# 2 dimensional arrays printing rows as columns java

Tags: java, arrays

We have been asked to print this 2D Array with the columns as rows

For example: the first column is 20,11,27 and it has to be printed:

20 
 11
 27

Here's my code so far and I can't even get it printing the columns normally, do any of you guys know what the problem is and if you can help me find a solution to the problem?

```
public class TwoDimensionalArrays
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    final int size1 = 2, size2 = 4, size3 = 5;
    int [][] numbers = {{20,25,34,19,33}, {11,17,15,45,26}, {27,22,9,41,13}};        
    int row = 0, col = 0;

        for(row = 0; row <= size1; row++); //loops through rows
        {
            for(col = 0; col <= size2; col++); //loops through columns
            {
                System.out.println(numbers[row][col]);
            }
        System.out.print("\n"); //takes a new line before each new print
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Smells an awful lot like homework :P

Comment: `System.out.println` already appends a newline, that's what the `ln` represents in addition to `print`.

Comment: for printing columns use System.out.print(colValue+"\t"); ->tab space between columns 
and once all the columns are printed use System.out.println(); ->new line

Comment: It's not homework haha, it's just something the lecturer asked us to research and see if we could get working, I like the way arrays work so I'm interested to get it working :P

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava: does that mind at all? he posted his own effort and has a question.. that's fine even if it was homework

Comment: Btw, there's a semicolon at the end of your for loop: `for(row = 0; row <= size1; row++); <- here` and at the inner loop as well.

Comment: @christian.s Its frowned upon. Check out the discussion on the meta or google it.

Comment: @christian.s http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 3):

Delete `;` in the end of the loops

like this :

```
for (row = 0; row <= size1; row++) //loops through rows
 {
   for (col = 0; col <= size2; col++) //loops through columns
    {
       System.out.print(numbers[row][col]+" ");
     }
    System.out.print("\n"); //takes a new line before each new print
  }
```

---

**The Output :**

```
20 25 34 19 33 
11 17 15 45 26 
27 22 9 41 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on some predefined sizes of the multidimensional arrays(better name is array of arrays). Always use the real size of the array like `numbers.length` and `numbers[0].length` or use for-each like this:

```
int [][] numbers = {{20,25,34,19,33}, {11,17,15,45,26}, {27,22,9,41,13}};        

for (int[] row: numbers){
    for (int num: row){
        System.out.print(num+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Result is this:

```
20 25 34 19 33 
11 17 15 45 26 
27 22 9 41 13
```

If you want that transposed, you could do it like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers[0].length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[j][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Now the result is:

```
20  11  27  
25  17  22  
34  15  9   
19  45  41  
33  26  13
```

**Note**: There's nothing like rows and columns in the array of arrays, only dimensions.

Comment: Ok so now I have it printing ok, the only problem is it is printing the columns straight across. Our lecturer asked us to find a way to print it out so that the rows are columns if you get what I mean? Cheers for the help with the getting it printed guys, can't believe it was a pesky semi-colon haha

Comment: IT wasn't very clear from your original question. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the sizes directly but you might have to calculate (or, to make it simpler, provide) the maximum length of an element.

Printing could then look like this:

```
int maxDigits = 2; //provided or calculated
int [][] numbers = {{20,25,34,19,33}, {11,17,15,45,26}, {27,22,9,41,13}};        
for( int[] row : numbers ) {
  for( int n : row) {
    System.out.print( String.format("%" + maxDigits + "d ", n) ); //creates the format string "%2d" for 2 digits maximum
  }
  System.out.println(); //takes a new line before each new print
}
```

Note that you should use `System.out.print()` for printing *without* linebreaks.

The output would then look like this:

```
20 25 34 19 33 
11 17 15 45 26 
27 22  9 41 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class rwr {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

final int size1=2,size2=4,size3=5;

        int[][] number={{34,34,33,33,44},{22,23,24,23,24},{23,44,55,66,66}};

        int row=0,col=0;

        for(row=0;row<=size1;row++){

            for(col=0;col<=size2;col++){

                System.out.print(number[row][col]+"\t");

            }
            System.out.print(" \n");
        }
    }

}
run:
34  34  33  33  44   
22  23  24  23  24   
23  44  55  66  66   
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```